# Connect to a docker container service inside WSL from Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Windows Subsystem Linux setup on my Windows 10 PC (Ubuntu 18.04).
I installed Docker toolbox on Windows, and running through a VM I can run docker commands normally by setting:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
```

I can access it fine and install/run docker containers correctly.
One of these services is a Kafka Connect container running on localhost:8084, which if created from my Windows.
I can access it from my Windows browser normally if I run this directly from the Ubuntu Subsystem, but if I run it from a docker container inside the Windows subsystem, I cannot access it, as if the port was not being correctly forwarded from the docker-compose file.
Here is the configuration to get this service running:

```
#
# This docker-compose file starts and runs:
# * A 3-node kafka cluster
# * A 1-zookeeper ensemble
# * Schema Registry
# * Kafka REST Proxy
# * Kafka Connect
#

version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"

  kafka0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka0:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
    - "zookeeper"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8081"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: "schema-registry"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082/"
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: "rest-proxy"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081/"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"
    - "schema-registry"

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "connect"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-config"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-offset"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-status"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"
    - "schema-registry"

  ksql:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: "ksql_service_docker"
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081/"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"
    - "schema-registry"

  connect-ui:
    image: landoop/kafka-connect-ui:0.9.7
    ports:
    - "8084:8084"
    environment:
      PORT: "8084"
      PROXY: "true"
      CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
    depends_on:
    - "connect"

  topics-ui:
    image: landoop/kafka-topics-ui:0.9.4
    ports:
    - "8085:8085"
    environment:
      PORT: "8085"
      PROXY: "true"
      KAFKA_REST_PROXY_URL: "http://rest-proxy:8082"
    depends_on:
    - "rest-proxy"

  schema-registry-ui:
    image: landoop/schema-registry-ui:0.9.5
    ports:
    - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      PORT: "8086"
      PROXY: "true"
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081/"
    depends_on:
    - "schema-registry"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "cta_admin"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "chicago"
      POSTGRES_DB: "cta"
    volumes:
    - ./producers/data/cta_stations.csv:/tmp/cta_stations.csv
    - ./load_stations.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/load_stations.sql
```

All other systems connect correctly and no error is logged when putting up all the docker-compose file.
I have tried using different ports but no luck.
Seems to me there is an issue in the binding of the docker host and the WSL host?

I would like to know:

How can I manage to connect from my Windows Chrome browser, to the service located in localhost:8084 according to the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't paste the full code of `docker-compose.yml` , what I guess is, your original docker-compose.yml has docker linked or networked with a kafka container named `connect`, so you can connect with `http://connect:8003`

But since kafka was installed in Windows directly (host server), the application container (kafka connect) doesn't know this host called `connect`

You can replace `connect` with your windows IP address.

```
  CONNECT_URL: "http://<your_windows_IP>:8083"
```

Comment: connect works well it seems, and the connect-ui service works well with it. I added the full docker-compose file in case you are able to see an issue. Also the issue is not the connect  url but the connect-ui service not being discoverable from the browser